# Mapping entity to json with object property (Generic type)

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping, jersey-2.0

I have 2 classes:
 Test1 -  capsulate result (entity) for response.

```
public class Test1 {  
    public String status_type;  
    public int error_code;  
    public String status_msg;  
    public Object data;  
}
```

Test2 - One of entity with I need to send, with additional fields. (Test1 class fields)

```
public class Test2 {
    public int idd;
    public String username;
}
```

Jersey rest service

```
@Path("test")
public class MyTest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Test1 getIt() {

        Test2 t2 =  new Test2();
        t2.idd = 1;
        t2.username = "Jony Jackson";

        Test1 t1 = new Test1();
        t1.error_code = 0;
        t1.status_type = "info";
        t1.data = t2;

        return t1;
    }
}
```

Result I've get:

```
{"status_type":"info",  "error_code":0,  "data":"rest.Test2@9707283"}
```

Result I needed to get:

```
{"status_type":"info","error_code":0, 
    "data":{"idd":1,"username":"Jony Jackson"}}
```

Please, help to fix this.

Comment: Just quick review, did not actually try it: in your class `Test1` instead of `public Object data;` it should be `public Test2 data;`. That must be the reason why it is not translating it properly. Hope it helps.

Comment: No, i have many classes, that's why I can't define exact type. Thanks you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem other ways.

```
@Path("test")
public class MyTest {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Object getIt() {

        Test2 t2 =  new Test2();
        t2.idd = 1;
        t2.username = "Jony Jackson";

        Test1 t1 = new Test1();
        t1.error_code = 0;
        t1.status_type = "info";

        String json = null;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false);
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL);
        try {
            t1.data = t2;
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(t1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return  json;

    }
}
```